# make fscanf() read the white space issue

Tags: c, string, scanf

I am trying to read a formatted input file where it contains 3 columns using `fscanf()` in C. Each line's format is 3 characters separated by a space like this

```
a hi c
i hello l
  abc z  //issue
2 mystr k 
...
```

The issue is it is not reading the column when there is a white space. My `fscanf()` function is the following:

```
while (fscanf(matrix, "%c %s %c\n", &one, &two, &three) != EOF) {
    ...
}
```

So say in the above case line#3, I want the white space to store in the variable "one".

I have tried some other suggestions online such as "%*1[\t]" but it does not help. Is there anyway that I can make this `fscanf()` reads the white space then store it into the char? Thanks

Comment: What behavior do you get? What happens if the line with white space at the start is the first line?

Comment: The trailing newline in the format string is a UX disaster, and breaks your input when the data comes from a file.  The `scanf()` family are lackadaisical about space; they'll skip it at the slightest opportunity (except for `%c`, `%n`, or `%[…]` (scan sets)).  You'll need to read each line and then parse it with `sscanf()` and your format string.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: What is the data type of `one`, `two`, and `three`? Are they of the same type? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 3):

First enable all compiler warnings.

--

Could use `fscanf(matrix, "%c%*c%5s%*c%c%*c", &one, two, &three) == 3`

But better to read a line with `fgets()` and then parse.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `fscanf` format string `"%c %s %c\n"` contains a trailing [whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) (in this case `\n`). This whitespace character tells `fscanf` to read and discard all whitespace characters from the input stream until it encounters a non-whitespace character.

Therefore, when `fscanf` reads the lines

```
i hello l
  abc z
```

it will successfully match `l`, `hello` and `l`, but then it will read and discard the whitespace characters `"\n  "`. However, you only want it to read and discard `"\n"`.

There are several ways of solving this problem:

1. Instead of using a whitespace character which instructs `fscanf` to read as many whitespace characters as possible, you can use the `%*c` format specifier to read and discard only a single character. However, this will only work if that character is guaranteed to be the newline character.
2. A more robust solution would be to first read the line using [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead of `fscanf`. In contrast to `fscanf`, `fgets` will always read exactly one entire line (if it can), so it will not leave any characters of a line on the input stream, and it also will not attempt to read characters of the next line. After reading the line and storing the line in a memory buffer as a string, you can use [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) on that memory buffer.

Here is an example of the second solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//forward function declaration
bool get_line_from_stream( char buffer[], int buffer_size, FILE *fp );

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fp;
    char line[200];

    fp = fopen( "input.txt", "r" );
    if ( fp == NULL )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    while ( get_line_from_stream( line, sizeof line, fp ) )
    {
        char one, two[20], three;

        if ( sscanf( line, "%c %19s %c", &one, two, &three ) == 3 )
        {
            printf(
                "Successfully read the following record:\n"
                "  One: %c\n"
                "  Two: %s\n"
                "  Three: %c\n",
                one, two, three
            );
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Parsing error!\n" );
        }
    }

    fclose( fp );
}

//This function will read exactly one line of input and remove the
//newline character, if it exists. On success, it will return true.
//If this function is unable to read any further lines due to
//end-of-file, it returns false. If it fails for any other reason, it
//will not return, but will print an error message and call "exit"
//instead.
bool get_line_from_stream( char buffer[], int buffer_size, FILE *fp )
{
    char *p;

    //attempt to read one line from the stream
    if ( fgets( buffer, buffer_size, fp ) == NULL )
    {
        if ( !feof(fp) )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        return false;
    }

    //make sure that line was not too long for input buffer
    p = strchr( buffer, '\n' );
    if ( p == NULL )
    {
        //a missing newline character is ok if the next
        //character is a newline character or if we have
        //reached end-of-file
        if ( !feof(fp) && getc(fp) != '\n' )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Line is too long for memory buffer!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //remove newline character by overwriting it with a null
        //character
        *p = '\0';
    }

    return true;
}
```

For the input

```
a hi c
i hello l
  abc z
2 mystr k
```

this program has the following output:

```
Successfully read the following record:
  One: a
  Two: hi
  Three: c
Successfully read the following record:
  One: i
  Two: hello
  Three: l
Successfully read the following record:
  One:  
  Two: abc
  Three: z
Successfully read the following record:
  One: 2
  Two: mystr
  Three: k
```